What is this green board behind my townhouse drywall?
I am mounting my TV and wanted to install an outlet to run the cables through the wall. I cut out a small chunk of drywall, because it seemed like something was behind it. When I pulled the piece out, it looks like there is a harder, green board about half an inch behind my drywall. This is a shared wall between a neighboring townhouse. Is it possible to mount an outlet here? There are other outlets on this same wall.

Pictures: https://imgur.com/a/uWUHvvl

could be firewall ... you probably have to get permission anyway

Almost certainly 2 layers of drywall to meet fire regulations. Might be a good idea to make sure your outlet is compliant.

Most rentals and multi-family buildings require a licensed electrician for that type of work.  You are probably limited by local regulations to changing light bulbs, turning off breakers, and maybe replacing switches/receptacles.
